# Communicating between multiple windows forms in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I'm working on a program that involves multiple forms triggered by buttons, events etc. 
And I'm having trouble passing and changing objects through multiple forms.

For example, say I have `form 1`, `form 2`, and `form 3`.

I have a list defined in form 1 but all 3 forms need to have the ability to change the values in that list?

I'm guessing it's not as simple as just writing:

```
Form1 frm1 = new Form1(); 

Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
```

etc...

What's a better way to do so?

Comment: There isn't a *better* way, only a *more complete* one.

Comment: If all form need to change then why not declaring that list as a static public variable.

Comment: @Esen static variables are not a nice way in C#, it's should be object-oriented

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any static members to get this done. I would suggest something lile the following:

1. Instantiate the list that will be accessible to all your forms. If you will data-bind some controls (listboxes, comboboxes, ...) to it, look into the `BindingList` type.
2. Have the forms' constructors accept a list which they will use e.g. as a data source to bind against.

   ```
   var list = new BindingList(...);
   var form1 = new Form1(list);
   var form2 = new Form2(list);
   ```
3. If your forms need to be opened all simultaneously, show them modelessly using the `Show` method instead of `ShowDialog`.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways to proceed, and it depends on the list :

- the list is a global variable, in this case, I think that you have de build a static class and put your list in it to be accessible for all.
- the list is not global, here you have to override the constructors of your forms et pass the list in every constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're creating the Form2 and Form3 from the Form1. You can simply make a property in these forms and pass the list to it (maybe with a constructor). Since lists are reference types, modifying it in Form2 would modify it in Form 1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a static global class that keeps all of your global accessible data.
Or you can pass the List created in first form to each subform via their constructors

For example: (in form1)

```
Form2 frm = new Form2(myList);
```

in form2

```
public class Form2:Form
{
    List<MyObjects> _globalList = null;

    public Form2(List<MyObjects> listData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _globalList = listData;
    }

}
```

then inside Form2 you can use the list passed and change/add/delete its elements. These updates will be visible also in Form1. Of course the same method could be applied when opening Form3.

The other solution requires the construction of a global static class dedicated to contains global values used everywhere in you application. If used with caution could be very useful.

In a GlobalData.cs file

```
public static class MyAppData
{
     public static List<MyObjects> GlobalData { get; set; }
}
```

in Form1

```
MyAppData.GlobalData = new List<MyObjects>();
MyAppData.GlobalData.Add(new MyObjects(......));
```

and in Form2

```
if(MyAppData.GlobalData.Contains(.......))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Singleton pattern?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 1):

You are actually doing what [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern try to solve. You'll need Models (your list or else), Views (your forms) and Controller. That way every views will be able to share/access data by using the controller

Answer (score 1):

Just make the list public if you don't want static list, then check from Application.OpenForms for the open form

```
if (Application.OpenForms["Form1"] != null)
{
    ((Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]).list[0] = 5;
}
```